# Error in trying to create a .vsix project (VS2017RC)

Tags: sdk, vsix, visual-studio-2017, project-template

I installed VS2017RC (15.0.26026.0) with Workloads '.NET desktop development' and 'Visual Studio extension development'. Furthermore, I installed the .NET Compiler Platform SDK.

When I create a new .vsix project via the template Code Refactoring (.VSIX), I get the error

`A problem was encountered creating the subproject 'CodeRefactorings1'. The imported project "$(VSToolsPath)\VSSDK\Microsoft.VsSDK.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find Microsoft.VsSDK.targets in the fallback search path(s) for ....`

I am unable to google a solution. Any ideas on how it may be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it, sort of. I can't reproduce it anymore with creating a new Code Refactoring, but I can when opening an existing VS2015 VSIX project in VS2017.

As a workaround/solution I created a new Code Refactoring in Visual Studio 2017, and copied all .cs files to those new projects, and reinstated references. So basically starting the project structure over from scratch.